# Cannot disconnect network share

Tags: windows, batch-file, network-share

Here's the problem.  I need to disconnect a network share using:

net use X: /delete /yes

I get the error "The device is being accessed by an active process."

No amount of scripting seems to let me get past this but if I simply open the My Computer and right click on the X: drive and hit disconnect, it works without a hitch.  I don't understand why I cannot do it from a command window but I absolutely need to within a script.

This is Windows Server 2003

Even if I could determine what processes to kill, that may be a way out.  I don't know.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this a permission issue? Have you tried running the batch file from an elevated command prompt as Administrator?

Comment: I don't see how it could be a permissions issue given that I can disconnect just fine from the GUI.

Comment: I don't see either, but did you try my suggestion? I have seen things like this before where AD is set wrong.

Comment: The user running the script is not an administrator.  You might say "aha!  that's it!!!" but then why can she do it in the gui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, even though I could **NOT** disconnect the network drive with the Map use /delete method, I **WAS** able to create a cscript  file as follows:

`Dim WshNetwork
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
WshNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive "E:"`

Why this works is beyond me.  But it does.  I did the entire script in VBS instead of a CMD file but, of course, you can mix them.